# how to get one specific value of all child in Fire base database using Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the names from my Firebase Database here is my code snippet.

```
databaseRef.child('Users').addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  //
  }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {

} };);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query all nodes of `Users`:

```
databaseRef.child('Users').addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         // parse the snapshot to your local model
         User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

         // access your desired field
         String name = user.getName();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  };
);
```

Comment: Thank you its prove helpful for me  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code...where UserDetails is a POJO class

```
datbabseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");    


databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                parkingList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    STSParkingDetails post = postSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                    UserDetails.class userDetails = new UserDetails.class(post.getName(),post.getAge(),post.getEmail(),post.getPhone());
                    parkingList.add(stParkingDetails);
                }
                saveParkingLocation();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception e = " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain the working of this line please.        
   STSParkingDetails post = postSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);